# I want a function to be fired whenever one option of a radio element is checked. How to do it using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, radio-button

There are many input radio elements on a web page and each radio element has several options. I want a function to be fired whenever one option of a radio element is checked. How to write the code using Jquery?
One input element looks as follows:

```
<div class="below">
<input type="radio" value="information" name="option0"/>
information
<input type="radio" value="communication" name="option0"/>
communication
<input type="radio" value="goods" name="option0"/>
goods
<input type="radio" value="attention" name="option0"/>
attention
</div>
```

I wrote the code as follows:

```
$(":radio").checked(function() {
    alert(this.value);

});
```

But it doesn't work. How to do it?

Comment: How to select those radio elements using Jquery?

Comment: The input radio code is dynamically created using Jquery.

Answer (score 3):

`checked` is not an event, you should use [`click`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) or [`change`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change).

Also I want to notice that is recommended to use `input:radio` instead of only `:radio`, because that [pseudo-selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/radio) will be evaluated as `*:radio` and it can be quite slow:

```
$('input:radio').click(function () {
  if (this.checked) { // or $(this).attr('checked')
    alert(this.value); // or alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work.unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'radio'

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? AFAIK, the `:radio` selector has been out there since the very early versions. You can check a sample of the code I posted, with your markup here: http://jsbin.com/utipo

Comment: Yes it works in your sandbox. But it doesn't work on my computer. Don't know why

Comment: I added <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I am using Firefox. On the error console, it says "unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'radio' "

Comment: That's normal and shouldn't stop it from working. jQuery tries to speed up some document queries by using the new Selectors-API to get the browser to do the matching. However `:radio` isn't a standard CSS selector (not even CSS3), it's one of the invented ones Sizzle implements, so Firefox gives you a warning. jQuery catches the resulting exception and uses the old, slower Sizzle code in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(':radio').click(function(evt){
    if ($(this).attr('checked'))
    {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work.unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element 'radio'

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://jsbin.com/uloniq/4) should do exactly what you want, but here is a synopsis:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function (event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    alert('Value "' + this.value + '" from option group "' + this.name '" was selected.');
  }
});
```

Explanation:

1. `$('input[type=radio]')` selects all radio buttons.
2. `.change()` sets the event handler for the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.  There is no "checked" event.
3. `this.checked` is `true` if the radio box is checked; `false` if not.  The event will fire not only for the option that was just checked, but also the one that was just unchecked as well.
4. `this.value` gives the value for the input.
5. `this.name` gives the name of the option group.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do it.

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
 alert($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: This code executes once for each currently-checked option, but the original question asks to execute code every time an option is checked (i.e., an event handler).